# sortableData break the testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-test

I have next snippet in my html

```
<tbody [sortableData]="myData">...</tbody>
```

receiving next error on unit testing

```
 Template parse errors:
    Can't bind to 'sortableData' since it isn't a known property of 'tbody'. ("
                  </tr>
                </thead>
              <tbody [ERROR ->][sortableData]="myData" > ...
```

It looks like I need to import some module, but I don't understand which one. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

actually adding  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ] fixing the issue

```
beforeEach(waitForAsync(() =>
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [...],
      imports: [...],
      providers: [ ... ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ],
    }).compileComponents()));
```